# NoMethodError: undefined method `has_many' for ActiveRecord:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to add user to table User by console : u=User.new but I always get an error ***undefined method `has_many' for ActiveRecord:Module*** and I tried many solutions but nothing helped so I tried to remove has_many relations ot avoid the error  I get the same error but with ***undefined method 'attr_accessor'***  or I get when I remove attr_accessor ***undefined method 'before_save'*** . i have another 4 models which are message-post-friendship-comment.

here is my  User Model

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::


  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
  has_many :messages
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends , through=> :friendships
  attr_accessor :email, :password
  before_save :encrypt_password
  after_save :clear_password
  validates_prescence_of :first_name
  validates_prescence_of :last_name
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates_prescence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email , uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates_prescence_of :gender
  validate :that_born_on_is_not_in_the_future



  def self.authenticate(email, password)
      user = find_by_email(email)
      if ((user && user.password_hash) == (BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.salt)))
       user
      else
        nil
      end
  end

  def encrypt_password
      if password.present?
        self.salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
        self.hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt)
      end
  end

  def clear_password
    self.password = nil
  end


  def that_born_on_is_not_in_the_future
      self.errors.add :birth_date, 'is in the future' \
  unless self.birth_date <= Date.today end


  end
```

***Thanks in advance.***

Answer (score 2):

This is probably causing that error.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::
```

`ActiveRecord` is a module, the class is `Base`.  It should be

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Comment: I feel totally confident this is the right answer. Noticed that immediately myself :)

Comment: @Swards I tried that but it caused another error which is **NameError: undefined local variable or method `through' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class** and when I removed this through relation it caused another error !

Comment: The `through` on this line needs to be symbol, otherwise ruby will treat it as a method `has_many :friends , through: :friendships`